# Cordova PayPal SDK shipping address configuration

Tags: cordova, paypal, cordova-plugins, payment-processing

I am using Cordova PayPal plugin: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin

I'd like PayPal to obtain shipping address from the buyer's account profile, if not set.
How to configure PayPal SDK to receive it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the answer received on the [issue you filed](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin/issues/34) in the Github repo....

"passing custom address functionality is available in the PayPal Mobile SDK but not yet implemented in the Cordova Plugin. Selecting shipping address is only available for PayPal if you using version above 2.4.1 for iOS and 2.3.0 for Android. See our documentation for iOS and Android for details, should you decide to extend the plugin via a pull request."